# Can't change flag-type

Tags: support, flags

During an edit-review I stumbled upon [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36788630/how-to-list-all-orecordbytes-in-orientdb/36817391#36817391) (now deleted, 10k only). So basically this was a "thank you"-post that the asker edited to an answer by copying in his existing answer. So I rejected the edit and flagged NAA. Now the edit has been approved, so it is no longer NAA, but keeping the duplicate answer would seem wrong to me too.

I tried flagging for moderator attention suggesting to delete the post, but now it says "You have already flagged this post for moderator attention". So I can neither retract my existing flag nor raise an additional flag.

So I've no way to draw attention to this aside from this meta-post.

Comment: FYI: I've deleted the answer and marked your flag as helpful; but what Glorfindel says in his answer is still relevant; declined flags are not the end of the world.

Comment: @Matt to me it wasn't about the declined flag but more about getting rid of the useless post. This has been done, so mission accomplished.

Answer (score 2):

Just leave a comment on the post, indicating that it is a duplicate. (The answer has been deleted in the meantime.)

In any case, flags cannot be retracted or changed ([yet](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87500/cancel-misclicked-flags/281010#281010)), so your flag could eventually be disputed or declined. This happens from time to time, but it is not the end of the world. As long as you keep your percentage of declined flags lower than 10% of your total flags, you won't even notice.

Comment: *flags cannot be retracted* - until [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/281010/191185) is rolled out (if it isn't already...)

Comment: @JonClements thanks - I forgot about this.